# C: strtok does not stop at delimiter and reads in excess items?

Tags: c, stdin, strtok

I am trying to create a routine that converts a user input buffer read from stdin
into an int array. I plan to allow the user to use either a space or a comma as a delimiter. This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc and realloc */
#include <string.h> /* for strtok */

#define BUFF 1024
#define INIT_CAP 3

int *getarr (char *buff, char *delim, int *len)
{
    char *token;
    size_t capacity, i;
    int elem, *arr;
    capacity = INIT_CAP;
    arr = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * capacity);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc");
        *len = -1;
        return NULL;
    }
    printf ("array capacity has been set to %lu\n", capacity);
    i = 0;
    token = strtok (buff, delim); 
    while (token != NULL) {
        if (sscanf (token, "%d", &elem) == 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "invalid input\n"); 
            *len = -1;
            return NULL;
        }
        printf ("read in element %d\n", elem);
        if (i == capacity) {
            capacity *= 2; 
            arr = (int *) realloc (arr, sizeof (int) * capacity);
            if (arr == NULL) { 
                perror ("realloc"); 
                break; /* return whatever has been converted */
            }
            printf ("array capacity has been doubled to %lu\n", capacity);
        }
        arr[i++] = elem;
        token = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }
    *len = i;
    return arr;
}

int main (void)
{ 
    char input[BUFF];
    int *arr, len;
    printf ("Array (space/comma delimited)? = " );
    if (fgets (input, BUFF, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "IO Error\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    arr = getarr (input, " ,", &len);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "failed to generate array from input buffer.\n"
                "Exiting process");
        exit (1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    free (arr);
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine when the user input does not contain any trailing space but the loop
runs an extra time when trailing spaces are provided. Here is some output to demonstrate what I am saying:

#### Without trailing spaces

[image]

#### With trailing spaces

[image]

I can take a guess at why this happens -- the loop probably runs an extra time and
the last value of `elem` is inserted into the array. But I cannot undertstand why
the loop should run when there is no token after the last space ? Here is an an extract from the man page for `strtok`:

> Each  call  to  strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token.  This string does not include the delimiting byte.  If no more tokens are found, strtok() returns NULL.

Any ideas on how I can get around this ?

Comment: Read the documentation for `strtok()` and `scanf()`. Step trough your code with a debugger.

Comment: The newline from `fgets` is the last token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fgets manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

That is, there is a trailing newline character in the buffer and thus as far as `strtok` is concerned there is an extra non-delimiter token after the trailing spaces. To fix that change the delimiter list to include newline:

```
arr = getarr (input, " ,\n", &len);
```

So why didn't `sscanf` flag an error when it tried to parse the newline as an int? It did but your error checking is wrong. From the [sscanf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf):

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.

That is, `EOF` can be returned on error. So your error check should instead be:

```
if (sscanf (token, "%d", &elem) != 1)
```